# How to change the parameters of request

Tags: php, symfony

I want to change some of the values passed in the request to see how the request behaves.

What I want to do is change it to the value of  `["content"] => int(2) "12"`.
I dumped `$brandevent` and it changed without any problems.

With the current code, I get the following error.
How can I solve it?

Error

> Expected argument of type "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request", "array" given

Controller

```php
$form = $this->createForm($articleType, $article, array(
     "method" => "POST",
     "login_staff" => $this->getStaff(),
));
$form =  $request->request->get('form');
$form['content'] = 12;
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
$request = $form;
 if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
     $eventService->saveEvent($event);
 return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($this->editRoute, array(
                    "articleType" => $articleType,
                    "id" => $article->getId(),
 )));
  }
}
$parameters['form'] =$form->createView();
return $this->render($this->getInputTemplate($articleType), $paramete
rs);
```

Tried Code

```php
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
 if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
     $form->get('content')->submit('12');
     $eventService->saveEvent($event);
  }
}
$parameters['form'] =$form->createView();
return $this->render($this->getInputTemplate($articleType), $paramete
rs);
```

Error

> A form can only be submitted once

Comment: since you are passing request you could just re-assign content. $request->request->get('content') = '12'

Comment: As mentioned, $data = $request->request->get('form') returns an array so passing it to handleRequest is not going to work.  Fortunately, there is a method that does.  $form->submit($data); might do what you want.

Comment: @RobertSaylor @Cerad Thank you for your comment.
Added Tried code.
I got a ```A form can only be submitted once``` error, but it seems that I have submitted the form twice.

Answer (score 1):

`handleRequest($request)` has now an array as argument and not a request anymore by overwriting

```
$request = $form;
```

Set the request content value before getting formdata to validate.

> Formdata always contains strings (due to $_POST)

```
$request->request->set('content', '12');
$form =  $request->request->get('form');
if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    if ($form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        $eventService->saveEvent($event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
When I tried it, I got an error of ```Error: Call to a member function createView() on null```.
I added the code of the question, but it seems that there is an error at ```$parameters['form'] =$form->createView();```, and if I delete this code, I get another error. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Oh, I don't have Symfony installed at all. I just referred to the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-request-data) for setting the requests data.